# Como hacer que aparezca el valor de los campos en pie de columna? Ireport y Jaspersoft

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jasper

Intento mostrar los valores del los campos en el pie de columna con la intención de que muestre la información debajo de detalle, sin embargo no muestra información. 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si lo que quieres es que esté justo debajo de detail, tienes que utilizar la banda summary.

Comment: Me fue de ayuda, Gracias @Dani